# OBIEE Error: [46137] CSF error encountered. Error code:43131

Tags: oracle, redhat, business-intelligence, obiee

I have install Oracle Business Intelligence 12c on Redhat Linux 7.0 using Oracle 12 C database. Three servers are failing to run or start and these are `obips1`, `Obisch1`, `obis1`. In the logs are receiving error `[46137] CSF error encountered. Error code:43131.`

How can I resolve this problem. I have checked user oracle accounts and are  showing that they are ok. Please help. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem when I used for the RCU a 12.2.0.1 Oracle database, there seems to be a bug in that version and Oracle support recommended using a 12.1.0.2.0 Database.
Regards